# Using windows REN command to remove a prefix from filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, brackets

I'm trying to come up with a solution for this issue using only windows cmd line if it's possible.

I have a series of files that look like the following,

```
[sometexthere233] Tv episode 1  
[sometexthere233] Tv episode 2  
[sometexthere233] Tv episode 3
```

I would like to detect any file names in the current directory that contain text within brackets as the prefix, and remove that portion of the file name.

```
Tv episode 1  
Tv episode 2  
Tv episode 3
```

I've done some research using the windows REN command, but I can seem to approach the right syntax or wild card for it to execute.

Any help on how to do this, or to create a bat file that is able to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible in batch, you would be better off using a real programming language, this would be much easier in C#

Answer (score 5):

The following script searches the current directory for files matching the mask `[*] *` and renames them by removing the bracketed part and the space after it:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("[*] *") DO CALL :process "%%F"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET oldname=%1
SET "newname=%~nx1"
SET "newname=%newname:*] =%"
RENAME %oldname% "%newname%"
```